# MIKRO ORM MIGRATION : TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'reduce')

Tags: node.js, database, orm, migration

I am trying to run migration create in **MIKRO ORM** but it gives following error:
[image: MIKRO ORM ERROR IN CREATING MIGRATION]

I also checked my mikro config file and the configs are as below:

```
const config: Options = {
  host: process.env.HOST,
  port: 5432,
  entities: ["dist/src/core/**/*.entity.js"],
  entitiesTs: ["src/core/**/*.entity.ts"],
  dbName: process.env.DB_NAME,
  type: "postgresql",
  user: process.env.DB_USERNAME,
  password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
  baseDir: path.resolve(), // defaults to `process.cwd()`,
  subscribers: [new BeforeCreateUpdateSubscriber()],
  migrations: {
    tableName: "mikro_orm_migrations", // name of database table with log of executed transactions
    path: "./dist/src/migrations",
    pathTs: "./src/migrations",
    glob: "!(*.d).{js,ts}", // how to match migration files (all .js and .ts files, but not .d.ts)
    transactional: true, // wrap each migration in a transaction
    disableForeignKeys: false, // wrap statements with `set foreign_key_checks = 0` or equivalent
    allOrNothing: true, // wrap all migrations in master transaction
    dropTables: true, // allow to disable table dropping
    safe: false, // allow to disable table and column dropping
    snapshot: false, // save snapshot when creating new migrations
    emit: "ts", // migration generation mode
  },
  debug: true,
};
```